# get updated on new chrome extensions added to store

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, browser-extension

Do you know if there is a way to register to an API/RSS other service that updates me when new google chrome browser app or chrome extension (but Not mobile app) is added to store?

Thanks